# Scroll to div animate Issue after updating my JQuery version

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I updated my jQuery from 1.9 to 3.1.1, and now I get an issue: `.animate` doesn't work.

I also added Migrate Plugin 3.0.0

My script is as follows:

```
$(function() {
   $('a.page-scroll').bind('click', function(event) {
      var $anchor = $(this);

      $('html, body').stop().animate({
         scrollTop: $($anchor.attr('href')).offset().top
      }, 1500, 'easeInOutExpo');

      event.preventDefault();
   });
});
```

Comment: can you pls mention what is the error you getting in console

Comment: what is the issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to change `.bind` to `.on`, because `.bind` has been deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

maybe this could help.

1. load first jquery
2. do the rest

```js
</script>

<script>
    $('a[href^="#"]').on('click', function(event) {

      var target = $(this.getAttribute('href'));

        if( target.length ) {
          event.preventDefault();
          $('html, body').stop().animate({
            scrollTop: target.offset().top
          }, 1000);
        }
    });


</script>
```

```css
.bl{
 height:750px;
 width:100px;
 background-color: #FF0000;
}
a{
display:inline-block;
height:50px;
width:100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.js" integrity="sha256-16cdPddA6VdVInumRGo6IbivbERE8p7CQR3HzTBuELA=" crossorigin="anonymous">
</script>
<a href="#page-scroll">clickhere to go to anchor</a>
<div class="bl">this is dummy div</div>
<a id="page-scroll" href="#">moved</a>
```